# Build Tree from List of "Contains" relationships

Tags: data-structures, tree, hierarchy, contains

I have a list of areas (A,B,C...) , each with a list of the towns (1, 2, 3, 4) they contain.

Note, these are NOT direct parents, the same town shows up in any area that contains it.

```
A: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
B: 2 3 4 5
C: 4 5
D: 2 3
E: 5 6 7
```

In my case, they always form a unique hierarchical relationship where an area can contain another area, along with the towns that are not in any of the child areas.

```
A: B E   1 8 9
B: C D
C:       4 5
D:       2 3
E:       5 6 7
```

If we assume that the hierarchy is unique, can someone give me a pointer to an algorithm in any general purpose language (or pseudo-code) (I'm using C#) to derive the hierarchy?

I've developed something that I think works, but I'd prefer something that's more mathematically certain than "this seems to work".

I'm perfectly happy to have it break if there is no unique hierarchy.

Many thanks

Comment: There are *hundreds*, if not thousands, of algorithm questions in StackOverflow.  Also, I don't think this question counts as "Conceptual Questions about Software Development".  Would it suddenly be alright if I had specified the answer must be in C#?
(To be honest, the split seems almost entirely arbitrary, except, no surprise, Programmer's StackExchange get's 1/100th the traffic.  Not a great move on StackExchange's part...)

Comment: This site is for troubleshooting errors in existing code; on the other hand, looking at the StackOverflow FAQ I think you're right that this could just as easily be posted here.  I retract my previous recommendation that it be moved to Programmers and apologize.

Comment: No apology needed.  Sadly I think the -1 on the question (by whomever) just doomed getting answers...

Comment: That was mine and it won't let me undo it.

Comment: C'est la vie.  I'll add my "seems to be working" algorithm answer to this question if I don't any replies in the next few days.

Answer (score 0):

My solution, which I *think* is correct, but is not efficient, is

(1) Determine the immediate parent area for each town:

For each town, find the area with the smallest number of towns that contains that town.

(2) Determine the immediate parent for each area:

For each area, find the area with the smallest number of towns that fully contains that area (not including itself, of course) [completely contain = all towns in area A are also in area B]

Again: this seems to work assuming that if a area X contains a town that area Y contains, then area X contains all the towns that area Y contains, or vice-versa.

In my case, I test this (again massively inefficiently, but I've got small (< 1,000 towns) data sets) by modifying step 1.  For each town, I find all areas that contain that town and sort them by number of towns in the area.  I then check that each area is a complete contained by the next area in the list.

If anyone has a known correct answer (or one more efficiently, I'd be grateful for your contribution.)